# What does "the syntax" or "semiotics" of taste mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I think it's a kind of analogy. Just as we understand a sentence, which is composed of a number of words, so we perceive a gustatory composition?

> Crushing the tongue against the roof of the mouth drives the food mass
> into the taste buds, and this clamping or sucking motion intensifies
> and prolongs the flavor. However, taste also requires the intervention
> of the brain which must recognize, evaluate, and categorize the
> stimuli from the mouth and nasal passages. The evaluative quality of
> taste or the recognition and judgment of flavor can be processed only
> in the brain, and, as with the visual imagery of painting, the quality
> of taste is assessed in relationship to a history of tastes. The
> tasting subject frequently judges the outcome of the experience in
> opposition to or alliance with previous experiences of the same or
> similar tastes. ***This process might be defined as the “syntax” or
> “semiotics” of taste.*** A chef or diner may rate a dish as “better”
> or “worse” than the last time the gustatory composition was prepared,
> or describe a new taste combination in relation to one that is
> familiar: “It tastes like chicken.”

[Food, Film and Culture: A Genre Study](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=rZwxNrX-bk8C&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=This%20process%20might%20be%20defined%20as%20the%20%E2%80%9Csyntax%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9Csemiotics%E2%80%9D%20of%20taste.%20A%20chef%20or%20diner%20may%20rate%20a%20dish%20as%20%E2%80%9Cbetter%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9Cworse%E2%80%9D%20than%20the%20last%20time%20the%20gustatory%20composition%20was%20prepared,%20or%20describe%20a%20new%20taste%20combination%20in%20relation%20to%20one%20that%20is%20familiar:%20%E2%80%9CIt%20tastes%20like%20chicken.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=1kxrQfZS2b&sig=ACfU3U0ZUhmYc5zyBzyhnoEvpWNrYr-GIQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEoOPv65HwAhUEZt4KHS0kDFUQ6AEwAnoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=This%20process%20might%20be%20defined%20as%20the%20%E2%80%9Csyntax%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9Csemiotics%E2%80%9D%20of%20taste.%20A%20chef%20or%20diner%20may%20rate%20a%20dish%20as%20%E2%80%9Cbetter%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9Cworse%E2%80%9D%20than%20the%20last%20time%20the%20gustatory%20composition%20was%20prepared%2C%20or%20describe%20a%20new%20taste%20combination%20in%20relation%20to%20one%20that%20is%20familiar%3A%20%E2%80%9CIt%20tastes%20like%20chicken.%E2%80%9D&f=false)

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. Note that because the author specifically says, "This process **might be defined as**...", he is telling you that he is proposing his own, non-standard coinage of this phrase.  You should not expect native speakers in general to understand "the syntax or semiotics of taste" unless they have read and agreed with this particular book.

Comment: It is poorly used, because semiotics studies systems of signs, and is not particularly adapted to studying taste. Nevertheless, the author means the language associated with describing taste. What tasters say about some taste or dish, for me, is what they say. I would say there is a *discourse* for talking about taste, not a semiotics of it. A *sense experience cannot be studied through semiotics*: only signs (language, pictures, gestures, movements,etc) can be.